# Accessing members of a gRPC Server class from services

Tags: c++, c++11, grpc

I am trying to learn how to use gRPC and make a simple server class that has some services that manipulate some shared data. As a first try, I put all the shared data in a class and instantiated that as a member of a server class. But it seems that the services cannot access the member variables of the server class.

Here is an example:

```
class grpcServices final : public bla::Services::Service {
 public:
  grpcServices() { test_3.reset(new std::vector<double>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}); };

  grpc::Status myServ(grpc::ServerContext *context,
                      const bla::Request *request,
                      bla::Responce *reply) override;

  void run(const std::string &server_address = "localhost:50051");

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server_;

  std::vector<double> test_1;
  std::vector<double> *test_2;
  std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>> test_3;
};
```

```
void grpcServices::run(const std::string &server_address) {

  test_1.push_back(2);
  test_2 = new std::vector<double>(4, 0);
  std::cout << "run -> test1 " << test_1.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "run -> test2 " << test_2->size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "run -> test3 " << test_3->size() << std::endl;

  test_3.reset(new std::vector<double>{0});
  std::cout << "run -> test3 " << test_3->size() << std::endl;

  bla::grpcServices service;
  grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
  grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin();
  grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
  builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
  builder.RegisterService(&service);
  server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
  std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;
  server_->Wait();
}

grpc::Status grpcServices::myServ(
    grpc::ServerContext *context, const bla::Request *request,
    bla::Responce *reply) {

  std::cout << "serv -> test1 " << test_1.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "serv -> test2 " << test_2->size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "serv -> test3 " << test_3->size() << std::endl;

  return grpc::Status::OK;
}
```

Calling first the run method from the main and then calling the myServe from the client I get:

```
run -> test1 1
run -> test2 4
run -> test3 5
run -> test3 1
Server listening on localhost:50051
serv -> test1 0
serv -> test2 18446744072591769856
serv -> test3 5
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the code clearly but it looks like you set the test variables in a different object. I think you should modify those of the object created by  `bla::grpcServices service` instead.